# How to read a file in Julia like Python

Tags: python, file, julia, file-read

Why is there a difference between these?:

```
# Python
f = open("./text.txt", "r")
for i in f.readlines():
   for l in i:
      print(print(l == "\n", ":", l))
f.close()
# -----------------------------

# Julia
f = open("./text.txt", "r")
while !eof(f)
    for l in readline(file)
        println(l == '\n', " : ", l)
    end
end
close(f)
```

The Python one outputs this:

```
False : h
False : e
False : l
False : l
False : o
False :  
False : W
False : o
False : r
False : l
False : d
True : 
                     <--- yep, it is as expected
False : y
False : a
False : y
```

The Julia one outputs this:

```
false : h
false : e
false : l
false : l
false : o
false :         <--- is this not a \n??
false : W
false : o
false : r
false : l
false : d
false : y
false : a
false : y
```

`text.txt` is this:

```
hello World
yay
```

As you can see the outputs are different. How can I make the Julia one behaves like the Python one? Are there other ways of reading a file in Julia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
# Julia
f = open("./text.txt", "r")
while !eof(f)
    for l in readline(file, keep=true)
        println(l == '\n', " : ", l)
    end
end
close(f)
```

By default, it discards `\n`'s, but you can keep them by adding `keep=true`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more Julian (and corrected) version using the `keep=true` suggestion by user17558100:

```
open("./text.txt", "r") do f
    for l in readlines(f, keep=true)
        foreach(c->println(c == '\n', " : ",c), l)
    end
end
```

This `do` format is the same as Python's `with` statement and this makes sure the file is closed without an explicit `close()` call.

Answer (score 2):

if you like to read a character at a time you should use `readeach`, e.g.

```
f = open("./text.txt", "r")
for l in readeach(f, Char)
     println(l == '\n', " : ", l)
end

false : h
false : e
false : l
false : l
false : o
false :  
false : w
false : o
false : r
false : l
false : d
true : 

false : y
false : a
false : y
```

BTW, just note that this is not an efficient way.